# How to upload different SDK versions of apk in market

Tags: android

Thanks for previous replies,

I want to release my apk in android market, actually i did my application in android sdk version 2.2. when i upload this apk in market, it only visible to below 2.2 or same versions of android devices, but my target is apk will also visible for tablet versions (ie) above 2.3 or 3. i googled this, and i found that android market supports multiple apk's to upload in market, so that we can separate our apk's for devices as well as for tablet versions. Is it possible to maintain single apk which should visible for tablet as well as device versions of android. i am not sure about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html) Android doc explains how to do exactly that.

This seems to be a new feature in Google Play. You are able to publish an App in "Advanced Mode"; you need to create filters based on elements in the Manifest of each version. Then, when somebody comes across your listing, it will present the version where the filter matches that user's system characteristics.

Currently, only 3 manifest elements are supported for multi-version filtering: sdk version (i.e. 2.2, 2.3, 3.0, etc), OpenGL capabilities, and screen size. I imagine they might add more here, but that is of course a guess.

Comment: Please add a little by way of explanation in addition to your link

Comment: good call, especially since "I googled this" in the question could mean the poster had already come across my linked page

Comment: Yes i know we can upload multiple versions of APK in market. but is it possible to give a single apk for both the versions..